# Getting Filtered results by Date column from a list with BCS and SharePoint 2010 JavaScript Client Object Model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, bcs, filter, date-time

I'm trying to get the filtered results by a column type DateTime from a list filled with BCS using JavaScript.
I've tried everything to get those results with query like:

```
"<Where>" +
    "<Geq>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Fecha'/>" +
            "<Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'>" +
                "3/12/2013" +
            "</Value>" +
    "</Geq>" +
"</Where>" +
```

also removing the IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'.
Does someone know the correct syntax for this query?
Or is it a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your datetime has to be converted into [ISO8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript) format. See [another question about it (but in server side)](/questions/25874/caml-query-not-working).

So, your date has to have the format: `2013-03-12T00:00:00.000Z`

In javascript you can do this:

```
var date = new Date(2013, 3 - 1, 12); //months are zero based
var iso = date.toISOString();
```

then iso string can be in the caml query.

I would also recommend the MIT licenced [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for parsing, processing, comparing and formating dates in javascript, and Ms-PL licensed [camljs](http://camljs.codeplex.com/) for creating complex (and simple of course) caml queries.

Comment: I've already tried the ISO format, but it just doesn't filter them.
Those JavaScripts might be useful, i will try them.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: paste this in your CAML Query  iso.ToString("s")